Faithful and simple $R$-modules and two-sided ideals of $R$
Suppose $R$ is a unital ring and M is a faithful (i.e. $\mathrm{Ann}_R(M)=0$
) and simple (i.e. no submodules other than 0
and itself) left $R$-module. I need to show that the only two-sided ideals of $R$ are trivial ones.
By contradiction, assume that there exists a two-sided ideal $J \neq 0, R$ of $R$. Let $x \in M$, and consider $Jx$. This is a submodule of $M$. Since $M$ is simple, we have $Jx \in \{0, M\}$. If $Jx = 0$, this contradicts the fact that $M$ is faithful. However, I am unable to conclude anything if $Jx = M$.
Thank you very much for the help.

Rings with a faithful simple left module are known as left primitive rings. Any simple ring is left primitive, but a left primitive ring need not be simple.

Why is there a downvote to someone who is just trying to ask for clarification on his/her thoughts?

@GeoffreyTrang This seems to be an answer, not just a comment. It explains why the claim is wrong.
